# 불안(不安) 부(不), 안(安) why is this liul inserted?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, hanja

I know hangul was originally written as Kanji.

`불안` should be written as `부안`, because `부` is "不", `안`　is "安".

Why is `부안` written as `불안`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, Hangeul was not originally written as Kanji.
Kanji is the term for Chinese characters used in the Japanese language; Hanja is the term for these characters used in Korean language.  Hangeul is another writing system for Korean.

不 actually has [2 pronunciations in Korean: 불 and 부](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/ccko/99415c9efec34a08ae1b19b6a88484e9).  This can be traced back to Middle Chinese, [where the pronunciation included  /pɨu/, /pɨuX/, /pɨut̚/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D).  The last one ends in a /t/; final /t/ in Middle Chinese characters normally correspond to a ㄹ 받침 in Korean.

The actual pronunciation of 不 in Korean somewhat depends on the following syllable, although there are many exceptions.  But in general:

1. [If the following syllable begins with ㄷ or ㅈ](http://haesol-ed.com/archives/1173), then 부 is more common: 부득이하다, 부적절하다.
2. In other cases, 불 is more common: 불안, 불리, 불상하다, 불쾌, 불행, etc.
3. But there are exceptions: e.g. 부실